# How does UNION in SQL Server compare one row to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is regarding the SQL `UNION` operator's **internal** way of finding duplicate rows -- not about writing our own query to compare 2 rows.

Consider, for example, I am using union with 2 select queries. Each select is joining 5 or 6 tables and having 10 columns in the result set.

The question is: how does `UNION` find the duplicate rows? Does it compare column1 of select1 with column1 of select2 && column2 of select1 with column2 of select2 ......?

When I have 10 columns in each select - the result contains 7000 rows (for example).

When I am have 9 or 11 columns in select statement (but no change in join/query logic) - the result contains different count of rows, not 7000.

Can anyone explain, how does `UNION` determine which rows are 'duplicates'?

Note: I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Column by column comparison should be the way. Even in relational algebra, union basically compares tuples from different relations element by element to determine if there are duplicates. See this: https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/bertino/348Spring2012/relational_algebra_and_calculus.pdf

Comment: The English is a tad shaky :) but I'm upvoting because the question is a valid one.

Comment: Is there a `timestamp` column anywhere in these queries?

Comment: @Shree.Pat18. Thanks for the useful link.

Comment: @John Doe, I will take this "tad" comment positively. Thanks for pointing it out.This will motivate me to improve further.

Comment: @DavidTansey, yes. some datetime columns are there.

Comment: There is no shame in learning a new tongue.  There is only shame in using that tongue to express dumb or bad ideas.  So you have nothing to feel ashamed about.

Comment: Thanks for the motivation @John Doe. As a newbie to stackoverflow, I feel supported. I didn't feel shame, but thought to put more effort to improve my tongue :-)

Comment: @DavidTansey, Thanks for your time for editing the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/), who has a long-running blog with lots of great information on T-SQL,

> A UNION statement effectively does a SELECT DISTINCT on the results set. If you know that all the records returned are unique from your union, use UNION ALL instead, it gives faster results.

`SELECT DISTINCT` will compare the vales of *all* columns, so if *any* value in *any* column is different, that row will remain, but if *all* values are the same, it will be removed from the results.  There are various rules for comparing column values that are of slightly different type, and you can't use columns where the type of the column in one part of the `UNION` can't be converted to the type of the corresponding column in the other part of the `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you so much James. This is what I was looking for :-)